# How do I use CSS flex to make two items float left and one float right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

I need to use CSS to make two items align left, one after the other, and the third item align to the right.

Traditionally I would have used `float: left` and `float: right` for this but it's no longer recommended.

How do I do it with flex or one of the modern CSS properties please?

I tried:

```
.flex-container {
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

This had the effect of everything floating left. I want to float one item to the right, but not all of them.

I've found an answer that does  `margin-left: auto;` on the third element but that looks like an ugly hack, is it the best option?

Comment: `margin-left: auto;` on the third element is not a hack at all, it's the common way to achieve this kind of alignment with flexbox.

Comment: what about align-self, why do they use margin-left instead of align-self?

Comment: align-self is a setting for the *cross-axis* of flex containers (in your case vertical) – what you want is alignment along the *main axis*. see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self

Comment: `justify-content` is a step in the right direction. Check out the link above where the question is already answered and also the docs for justify-content: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

Comment: @Johannes that explains why align-self didn't work, thanks